# Select objects with checkboxes in Class Based ListView

Tags: python, django, listview, django-templates, django-views

I'm a django newbie, I'm making a little app to record work calls received during nighttime.
At the moment the app works fine. I have made a form to fill call data, which is then presented as a table using a generic ListView.

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
   login_url = '/login/'
   redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
   template_name = 'chiamate/list_full.html'
   context_name = 'lista_chiamate'
   def get_queryset(self):
       return Chiamata.objects.all
```

Here is the code for the template:

```
{% extends 'chiamate/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url "chiamate:inserimento chiamata" %}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nuova Chiamata</a>
<p></p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, Guest please <a href="{% url 'login' %}">[login]</a></p>
{% endif %}

    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <form action="{{ action }}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
    {% for chiamata in object_list %}
        {% if chiamata.data_chiusura.weekday == 4 or chiamata.data_chiusura.weekday == 5 or chiamata.data_chiusura.weekday == 6 %}
            <tr class="info">
        {% elif chiamata.data_chiusura == None  %}
            <tr class="danger">
        {% else %}
            <tr>
        {% endif %}
                <td><input class="checkbox" name="chiamata_mail" type="checkbox" id="checkbox_{{ chiamata.id }}"value="{{ chiamata.id }}"></td>
                <td class="txtdata">{{ chiamata.utente.get_full_name|wordwrap:5  }}</td>
                <td class="txtdata"><a href="{% url 'chiamate:dettaglio chiamata' chiamata.id %}">{{ chiamata.data_chiamata|date:"l d M Y H:i" }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ chiamata.interlocutore }}</td>
                <td>{{ chiamata.testo_chiamata|truncatechars:200 }}</td>
                <td class="txtdata">{{ chiamata.reperibile|wordwrap:5 }}</td>
                <td>{{ chiamata.data_chiusura|date:"H:i" }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'chiamate:modifica chiamata' pk=chiamata.id %}" class="btn btn-success" ><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'chiamate:cancella chiamata' pk=chiamata.id %}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <input id="send_selected" type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    </table>
    </dv>
{% endblock %}
```

I've already tried to add the checkboxes here. When I do, they show on the page but then when I press the send button (currently implemented as a form send, but I want to use a bootstrap button) I don't know how to pass the objects to the email function, or at least show them in a new page.

Answer (score 1):

You should define the `post` method of your view:

```
class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       return ChiamataUpdateView.as_view()(request)
```

And handle the post data on the other view.

Also, you `get_queryset` isn't returning a queryset since you're not calling `all()`. It should be:
`return Chiamata.objects.all()`